# Save all open files in current folder and subfolders

Tags: files, saving, directories

Some of my projects are organised in way that the there isn't one make file at the top route of the project (git/svn/...) folder but I have several small Makefiles in subfolders of the project. Normally I use Projectile to save only files related to my current project and call the main Makefile but this doesn't work if the Makefiles are more distributed in the project.

I would like to have a function that saves all open/unsaved files from the current folder and it's subfolder and then run the Makefile in the current folder.

```
(defun max/save-compile-current-folder ()
    (interactive)
    (max/save-current-and-subfolder-files ...)
    (compile t))
```

I currently don't know how to write the function `max/save-current-and-subfolder-files`. I would appreciate any hints how to write this function or links to libraries that already implement it.

Comment: I would be astonished if Icicles couldn't do that...

Comment: Also, you might want to write a function firing `save-some-buffers` with a suitable second argument.  See the docstring for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just added this feature to [helm-make](https://github.com/abo-abo/helm-make).
Give it a go and let me know if it works as you wanted, you
just need to set the custom:

```
(setq helm-make-do-save t)
```

Here's the code that does it:

```
(when helm-make-do-save
  (let* ((regex (format "^%s" (regexp-quote default-directory)))
         (buffers
          (cl-remove-if-not
           (lambda (b)
             (let ((name (buffer-file-name b)))
               (and name
                    (string-match regex (expand-file-name name)))))
           (buffer-list))))
    (mapc
     (lambda (b)
       (with-current-buffer b
         (save-buffer)))
     buffers)))
```

Comment: awesome it works great thank you. This is also a good reason to start to get into helm.

Comment: Note that this won't save files in the same directory tree but accessed through symbolic links, which is probably desirable here. Also, take care to protect metacharacters when you build a regexp.

Answer (score 2):

The simple thing would be to save everything with `C-u C-x s` (mnemonic: `C-x s` is a slightly awkward modification of `C-x C-s` which is the normal save command). The computer takes less time to save everything than you'd lose worrying what not to save. This runs the command [`save-some-buffers`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Commands.html#index-save_002dsome_002dbuffers-1062). With no prefix argument, you'll be prompted whether to save each modified buffer.

If you really want to save only some files, you can write a function that only saves files based on your chosen criteria.

```
(defun save-buffers-in-directory-tree (directory)
  "Save buffers that are visiting a file in the current directory and its children."
  (interactive (list default-directory))
  (setq directory (file-name-as-directory (file-truename directory)))
  (mapc (lambda (buffer)
          (let ((filename (buffer-file-name buffer)))
            (when (and (buffer-modified-p buffer) filename)
              (setq filename (file-truename filename))
              (when (string-prefix-p directory filename)
                (with-current-buffer buffer
                  (save-buffer))))))
        (buffer-list)))
```